# Excel Match If Greater than Zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I'm working in excel and i want to use the formula MATCH to retrieve the row of each number greater than zero in a column. For example, having the next column

```
Number 
  0
  0
  6
  1
  0
  8
  0 
  0
  0
  0
  10
```

I want to obtain in other column the following:

```
Rows
  3
  4
  6
 11
```

¿Is it posible to do this with the MATCH formula?
If not, then ¿How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the range A2:A12, then try this **Array Formula** which requires confirmation with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

In B2

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$12>0,ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(B$2:B2)),"")
```

Confirm with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and then copy it down until you get blank cells.

Adjust the ranges as per requirement, but don't refer the whole column reference like A:A in the formula.

Comment: You're welcome Xhoan! Glad it worked. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
B1:    =MATCH(TRUE,A:A>0, 0)                              Ctrl+Shift+Enter

B2:    =IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,(A:A>0)*ROW(A:A)>B1, 0),"")    Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

copy `B2` and paste along column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the range `A2:A12`.

1. Select the cells B2:B12. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>. It will allow you to enter values in the `B2` cell.
2. Copy paste the below formula in the `B2` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

`=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(A2:A12<>0,ROW()-ROW(A1),NA),ROW()-ROW(B1)),"")`

Note if you select only B2 and enter the formula then you will get only the top one value. Adjust ranges accordingly if required.